# Conditional Rendering with React-semantic UI

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react, conditional-rendering

I'm trying to render the React-Semantic UI Message and based on the condition I need to display Content or list based on the condition.

Working code:

```
const Message = ({icon, header, content, className, list}) => {
if(Array.isArray(content))
{
    return (
    <SemanticMessage
        icon={icon}
        header={header}
        className={className}
        list={content}
    />
    )
} else {
    return (
    <SemanticMessage
        icon={icon}
        header={header}
        className={className}
        content={content}
    />
    )
}
}
```

But this is not working:

```
const Message = ({icon, header, content, className, list}) => {
 return (
     <Message
         icon={icon}
         header={header}
         className={className}
         {...Array.isArray(content) ? [list={content}] : [content={content}]}
     />
 )

}
```

any leads? what I am missing here?

Answer (score 2):

You need to slightly modify the spread to spread an **object** with key/value pairs as opposed to spreading an array. These are known as **spread attributes** in JSX:

```
const Message = ({icon, header, content, className, list}) => {
 return (
     <Message
         icon={icon}
         header={header}
         className={className}
         {...Array.isArray(content) ? { list: content } : { content } }
     />
 )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Content property is missing.

```
return (
     <Message
        // this content prop missing in your code
         content={...Array.isArray(content) ? [list={content}] : [content={content}]}
     />
 )
```

Comment: No.. It's required